# Facebook login redirect after callback.php

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

The Facebook API pretends to get user back to callback page on local web site after successful login. But I need user back to the page where he pressed "facebook login". How can I put URL to request to get it back on callback.php?

Comment: add header('Location: facebook_login-php') at the very top to your callpack.php

Comment: and post some code for us

Comment: @Blueblazer172 I mean that now I have 

 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 
  'app_secret' => 
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email','user_hometown']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://abc.ru/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

And after login user goes to fb-callback.php.

Then I need to forward him to the page from where he pressed "Login via Facebook". I need add this URL somehow to request.

Comment: please put this code readable in your question by editing it.

Comment: @Blueblazer172

`$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '', 
  'app_secret' => '',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email','user_hometown']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://ru/fb-callback.php', $permissions);`

Comment: @Blueblazer172 
I put it in ` but it's displayed only so.

Answer (score 0):

Well...As it looks now, we can just add $_GET value to the callback URI and Facebook will get it back.